# .htaccess redirects not redirecting

Tags: .htaccess

I've set up redirects in a .htaccess file as follows:

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^windward\.net$ [NC]
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^$
 RewriteRule ^/author/bassemm/$ https://www.windwardstudios.com/team [L,R=301]`
```

However, when I go to URL http://www.windward.net/author/bassemm/ I'm not redirected to https://www.windwardstudios.com/team. Is there an issue with the way I set up the redirect in the .htaccess file?

Thanks

Comment: Is there a rewrite rule that might be getting invoked *before* this one?

Comment: Yes, there are a lot of redirect rules before this one in .htaccess. Is there anything that I should be looking for, as to why this isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

`RewriteRule` directive uses a relative URI path as its old path argument. You are using an absolute path `/author/bassemm/` that is why your rule didn't work. You need to use a relative URI path starting without `/` .

```
 RewriteRule ^author/bassemm/$ https://www.windwardstudios.com/team [L,R=301]
```

and change your RewriteCond

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^windward\.net$ [NC]
```

to

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^(www\.)?windward\.net$ [NC]
```

To redirect both www and non www versions of your domain.